# Powershell assign variable to registry path

Tags: powershell, variables, registry

Have this simple ps script where I want to replace `'HKCU:\Control Panel\Mouse' -Name SwapMouseButtons` with a variable.

```
if ((Get-ItemPropertyValue 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Mouse' -Name SwapMouseButtons) -eq 0) {Set-ItemProperty 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Mouse' -Name SwapMouseButtons -Value 1}
else {Set-ItemProperty 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Mouse' -Name SwapMouseButtons -Value 0}
```

I tried

```
$mouse = 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Mouse -Name SwapMouseButtons'
if ((Get-ItemPropertyValue ${mouse}) -eq 0) {Set-ItemProperty $mouse -Value 1}
else {Set-ItemProperty $mouse -Value 0}
```

but did not work

Comment: You can't pass a variable continuing both a value and an additional parameter, Powershell doesn't interpret it as a literal string. Get-ItemPropertyValue will be looking for a key called `HKCU:\Control Panel\Mouse -Name SwapMouseButtons`. You can set multiple variables, like `$key = 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Mouse'; $property = 'SwapMouseButtons'` and then use them in your commands like `Get-ItemPropertyValue $key -Name $property`

Comment: You could use [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) and combine both parameters 'Path' and 'Name' in a single Hashtable variable: 
`$splat = @{ Path = 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Mouse'; Name = 'SwapMouseButtons' }`. Then use this like so: `Get-ItemPropertyValue @splat` and `Set-ItemProperty @splat -Value 0`

Comment: @Theo Please make your comment the answer and I will gladly accept it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from my comment, you can combine the path string and the value name for the registry in a single Hashtable.

Then, use [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) to feed these values as parameters to the `Get-ItemPropertyValue` and `Set-ItemProperty` cmdlets

```
$splat = @{ Path = 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Mouse'; Name = 'SwapMouseButtons' }
# toggle the new value. 0 --> 1 and other values --> 0
$value = 1 - [bool]([int](Get-ItemPropertyValue @splat))
Set-ItemProperty @splat -Value $value
```